# ArduinoJson library parsing error

Tags: arduino-ide, esp32, json, mqtt

I am trying to retrieve JSON mqtt message I received in ESP32.

```
void mqttMsgCallback(char* topic, byte* payload, unsigned int length) {
    payload[length] = '\0';
    String _message = String((char*)payload);
    String _topic = String(topic);
    if (_topic.equals("Sys.GetInfo/"+getMacAddr()) == 1)
    {
      Serial.println("Message arrived for sys.GetInfo");
      StaticJsonDocument <256> msg1;
      Serial.println(_message);
      deserializeJson(msg1,_message);
      String callbackTopic = msg1["callbackTopic"];
      Serial.println(callbackTopic);
    }
}
```

The issue is when I publish `mosquitto_pub -t "Sys.GetInfo/2462ABFC2CD0" -m "{"callbackTopic" : "1234"}"` it works well like callbackTopic as 1234.

but when I publish `mosquitto_pub -t "Sys.GetInfo/2462ABFC2CD0" -m "{"callbackTopic" : "xyz"}"`  it prints callbackTopic value as null.
Please point me if I an missing something.

Arduino version 1.8.15
ArduinoJson : 6.18.2
Borad : ESP32

Thanks

Comment: Check the return value of `deserializeJson()` to see if it can even parse it as valid JSON.  Maybe you need `'{"callbackTopic" : "xyz"}'` (single quotes round the outside) to preserve the quotes on the inside.

Comment: @Majenko it works when i publish like ```'{"callbackTopic" : "xyz"}'```. Thanks 
why the message with "" works when `callbackTopic` value is numeric

Comment: Probably because the value is numeric. 1234 is a valid "thing" - xyz isn't.  "xyz" is, though, and if your shell is stripping the " because it's not either escaped or encapsulated within single quotes, then it can't parse `xyz` as a valid "thing".

Comment: `payload[length] = '\0';` how do you know there is a length + 1 position available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your shell is stripping the " from inside the string. If you run the command:

```
$ echo "{"callbackTopic" : "xyz"}"
```

you get:

```
{callbackTopic : xyz}
```

so you see all the quotes are stripped. `xyz` isn't something that ArduinoJSON can parse. But `1234` is, so with the quotes stripped it's still considered valid.

You need to ensure the quotes aren't removed. There's two ways of doing this: escaping them, or encapsulating the string in single quotes which gives a more "literal" interpretation of the contents than double quotes:

Escaping:

```
"{\"callbackTopic\" : \"xyz\"}"
```

Single quotes:

```
'{"callbackTopic" : "xyz"}'
```

Either of those when used as a parameter to a command work - like:

```
$ echo '{"callbackTopic" : "xyz"}'
{"callbackTopic" : "xyz"}
```

Answer (score -1):

To parse an ArduinoJSON one simply needs to

```
  String JSONpayload = "some JSON here";
  StaticJsonDocument <512> geoLocationInfoJson;
  DeserializationError error = deserializeJson(geoLocationInfoJson, JSONpayload);
  if (error) {
    this->mserial->printStrln("Error deserializing JSON");
  }
```

To use the values within the `StaticJsonDocument` one first needs to

```
if ( geoLocationInfoJson.isNull() == true ){
  String dataStr="NULL geoLocation data.\n";
  Serial.print( dataStr); 
  return true;
}
```

next, is required to verify if a key exists. If TRUE, then is mandatory first to get the desired value into a corresponding data type, like below, and only afterward work on it, for instance, send it as a BLE message string:

```
if(this->interface->geoLocationInfoJson.containsKey("lat")){
  float lat = this->interface->geoLocationInfoJson["lat"];
  dataStr += "Latitude: "+ String(lat,4) + "\n";
}
if(this->interface->geoLocationInfoJson.containsKey("lon")){
  float lon = this->interface->geoLocationInfoJson["lon"];
  dataStr += "Longitude: "+ String(lon,4) + "\n";
}

if(this->interface->geoLocationInfoJson.containsKey("regionName"))
  dataStr += String(this->interface->geoLocationInfoJson["regionName"].as<char*>()) + ", ";
```

The full code above is available on this GitHub repository:

https://github.com/aeonSolutions/aeonlabs-ESP32-C-Base-Firmware-Libraries

Comment: what question does this answer?

Comment: The one of successfully parsing an arduinojson object. And access key, value pairs it holds

Comment: that is not the question asked on top of this page

Comment: Read between the lines ?

Comment: the existing accepted answer shows what the problem was

Comment: As I mentioned before. Read between the lines.